# Laravel 8. Как сделать, чтобы не пропадало введённое значение полей формы в laravel

Tags: laravel

Laravel 8. Как сделать, чтобы не пропадало введённое значение полей формы в laravel. У меня при перезагрузке страницы пропадает всё что я вводил.

Comment: Ответ на вопрос будет проще дать, если Вы объясните, почему это не должно пропадать после перезагрузки страницы, потому что какой сюрприз, но по-умолчанию это так везде и работает.

Comment: понятное дело всё пропадёт. После перезагрузки память полностью очищается. И далее страница формируется заново. Разберитесь как вообще работает язык и http. Если говорить конкретно про ларавель, то он в сессиях возвращает старые значения. Читайте документацию, там целый раздел

Comment: Если под "перезагрузкой" имеется в виду "отправка формы", то для этого есть `old('name')`

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить значения ввода полей можно данной конструкцией *old('name')*, где *name* - значение *name* инпута.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
<input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]